# Bluetooth data transfer between two countries

Tags: bluetooth

I have a simulation device which is capable of transmitting data, over bluetooth, to a mobile app. When both the devices are kept in close proximity, the data transfer works fine. However now for some legal obligations, I cannot bring the simulation device to my country of work neither can I keep the mobile phone away from me. Thus parting the bluetooth transmitter and receiver countries away.

Is there a way by which I can capture the bluetooth data from transmitting device send it over internet to my country of work and then populate the data on my mobile app over bluetooth again?

Comment: Why do you need bluetooth again in your country. Upload the data to a service and fetch from that service at your country ?

Comment: This will be way harder to do it the way you described rather than switching to Ethernet frames altogether ...

Comment: @vizsatiz I am new to bluetooth technology, hence I am not able to understand your response. Will you please elaborate on how can we upload data to a service?

Comment: @ArthurAttout - The simulation device is maintained by a third party manufacturer, hence we cannot change anything within the device.

Comment: You'll have to make things on your own, as @vizsatiz said. Create an intermediate program that receives the bluetooth frames, and sends them through the network via websocket, or something similar. On the other end, create another intermediate device that listens to these incoming ethernet/wifi  frames and broadcast them via bluetooth so that your final device can listen to it. You'll have a very very **very** hard time doing this if nothing can be changed both on the sender and receiver side.

Comment: We are trying to use Raspberry Pi as intermediate devices at both the locations. And yes as rightly said, we are going through very hard times to figure how to receive the data from simulation device and publish it over the mobile app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this one, as it is way too broad. Please consider asking focused question, preferably that includes the code you've written so far to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, upload the byte stream to some data store (db or a kafka stream) from the source device. Now in your country, you can listen to this data/stream in different ways. Simplest would be exposing the data as a Web Service or overkill it by having another IOT listen to the stream and transmit that over bluetooth