# Transferring Bluetooth connection via the Internet

Tags: bluetooth

I was always wonder what would it be my first question on StackOverflow since everything I'm looking for is already asked. (Find only one similar here [Bluetooth data transfer between two countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948008/bluetooth-data-transfer-between-two-countries) )

**BACKGROUND STORY:**

From when it comes I’m a fan of Nokia N-GAGE. It’s a Nokia’s phone from 2003 with dedicated games. In its heyday 2003-2007, it has single-player, multi-player via Bluetooth and using a dedicated internet service N-GAGE ARENA for compete with people all over world.
N-GAGE ARENA servers were disabled about 2008 and as far i understand It isn't even worth trying to resurrect such a infrastructure. Mainly because it requires modifying the code of each game and that's illegal.
Multiplayer mode using Bluetooth work fine, but requires opponent 5m away max.
Nokia sold 1mln copy of this phone, and still are people all over world collecting n-gage games. I have a dream, I want to reactivate the possibility of playing multiplayer with people from all over the world.

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:**

I want to use the Bluetooth multiplayer mode by extending the usual N-GAGE to N-GAGE Bluetooth connection with an additional 3 elements. Two N-GAGEs, instead of connecting directly to each other as host-join, connect via a PC / smartphone applications that communicates with the server that transmits full data sent from the game of one user to game of the opponent.

[image: structure draw]

I admit that I do not have full knowledge of technical limitations. In my opinion, as a software engineer, it is theoretically possible, but I want to consult you, people more familiar with the subject. Maybe someone is working on a similar project and can comment.

**WHAT DO I KNOW:**

The application would have to transmit all data from the Bluetooth connection so as not to disturb the illusion of a direct connection between N-GAGEs.

The application must enable the selection of an opponent on the basis of the game. The choice itself could be made on the basis of some kind of chat in which users first define what they are playing, who’s the host, and then the connection is made.

**WHAT DO I WANT TO KNOW:**

Does what I describe is even possible?

Is such capturing Bluetooth connection and forwarding is even possible?

Does the development of technology in these 15 years allow me to transfer Bluetooth connection real time through 2 additional devices and Internet connection?

**I WOULD BE GREATFUL FOR:**

Any technical tips, literature that can help me to understand my limitations.

Any constructive criticism. Of course before I start doing such a project I have to confirm that isn't a utopia. For me It’s a side project, I’m able to spend years on it, but don’t want to get to dead end after all effort.

Comment: Bluetooth knows how to communicate with other Bluetooth objects by the [profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/) that is used. It would be useful to know what Bluetooth Profile is being used for the games. Hopefully it is using [PAN](https://docs.huihoo.com/symbian/s60-5th-edition-cpp-developers-library-v2.1/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/guide/Short-Link-Services-subsystem-guide/ShortLinkServices/BluetoothProfiles/BluetoothPAN/BTPANProfileOverview.html) which supports standard IP-based network services deployed over the Bluetooth transport layer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I feel like it's a good lead for first step. Unfortunately it's not a PAN. N-gage's Symbian is 6.1 and PAN is in use since Symbian 8.1. Right now I'm collecting information's on BT profiles and trying to get to the point by eliminating from [Bluetooth 1.1 profiles](https://www.amd.e-technik.uni-rostock.de/ma/gol/lectures/wirlec/bluetooth_info/profiles.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Does what I describe is even possible?**
Yes, yes it does. Your hardest part will be setting up a tranceiver to interpret the I/O. Your failure point would be super-encrypted messages and making transmission difficult...

If it's clear I/O you can signal this through any server and output it back to the tranciever to output. Confusing but possible just not sure of the design or how bluetooth sends its data.

**Is such capturing Bluetooth connection and forwarding is even possible?**
If a connection is possible then forwarding it is too. Considering this piping the transports.

**Does the development of technology in these 15 years allow me to transfer Bluetooth connection real time through 2 additional devices and Internet connection?**
Bluetooth real-time no... with added network latency, you're looking at anything from 1-200ms~. you may be able to improve it?

Overall I think if you can:

1. Connect the device to PC, and have PC talk back to device through blue-tooth
2. Read the data that goes in and out
3. Encryption proves little or none at all to be able to signal the data properly, tricky to explain you'll know though if there's a wall.

All should be possible it doesn't overly go against the grains but do more homework this is very valid.

Comment: Your message gives me hope it's possible. There is a lot of homework ahead of me but it's worth doing.